# How do I point a domain and subdomain to different hosting companies?

Tags: dns, subdomain, hosting, web-hosting

I'm having a slight issue. We have a domain www.example.com that's being hosted by a membership services company. We have a staging site in different hosting provider (provider X) as well.

The goal is for the staging site to take the main domain www.example.com and the current site to take members.example.com.

These two sites are in completely different hosting companies and the domain is currently pointed at the membership services company's host.

The CEO doesn't want to transfer the sites off the membership services hosting company into provider X yet wants both of them up and running. How do I handle this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not programming related.

Comment: Similar questions have been asked from this community and I used the right tags for the problem. Thanks.

Comment: And most of the time those questions get closed with extreme prejudice.   It's more appropriate for https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Cool. I could care less about prejudice. I'll check out the other community and see if similar questions get answered there. 

Either way, I got my answer and that's what I needed. Next time, it might help you to actually be helpful to someone. You've been around this platform for over 9 years right? Don't expect someone who just joined to know what you do. That's ignorant.

Have a good day.

Comment: I got over 250k reputation points from being *extremely helpful* to thousands of posters here.  Part of being in the community is knowing when *not* to answer a question because it's *off topic*.  Ironically the people that mostly answer those are generally also new users who don't know that, as happened here.  Here's the link to what's *on topic* - https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0):

You will need to point your domain to GoDaddy and create an A record in your GoDaddy DNS to point back to your other host. Your A record would have 'members' set as the host and the IP would be that of the membership services host.

Comment: Thanks Jake. I really appreciate it.